# .htaccess rule to change hosts for SEO

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting, seo

I want to migrate one of my client's website from a free host to paid host. Currently, the site/domain is being hosted inside a sub-folder (used this tut: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347) at the free host. I would like to move the site to the paid host, though at the new host the site WILL NOT be inside sub-folder.

From an SEO perspective, Do I need to tell google (using .htaccess) that the site has been migrated to paid host and no longer hosted inside a sub-folder.

thanks
dkj

Answer (score 1):

You have two "best" options here:

1. Use a 301 "Moved Permanently" Redirect on the existing pages. If you can create `.htaccess` files with Mod_Rewrite or Mod_Redirect directives this should be pretty easy.
2. Add a "Canonical" meta-tag header to the old site (or both sites) specifying the new page locations. [Google directions](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

The first is almost certainly less work, if either of those options are available. The latter always works, even on servers where you have no control, no `.htaccess` files, no nothing.